# Detect Strings that are already hashed in paragraph of text using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

What I'm trying to do is essentially split a url and extract words from the url, however, in a lot of cases urls can contain strings that are alphanumeric hashes or forms of illegible text.

Take the following example:
http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/15321408dd97beb7b5a94f0957b215cf/black-and-white-photography-portrait-of-brad-pitt.jpg

We have a descriptive url that keywords could be extracted from. The biggest problem with those keywords is that `15321408dd97beb7b5a94f0957b215cf` is one of them. Running spellcheck isn't necessarily the best option because it may filter out certain keywords that haven't been added to the spellcheck model. Manually curating that isn't possible right now. Also, that string varies in length and is not consistent. While the string in question appears to be md5, we know that the positions of digits to letters can change, so we'd need to account for that as well as variable length. Thinking aloud, almost something that just determines if the string is a hash or not...

Tools I am using:
Python
Spacy

My script below gives the following output:

- wp
- content
- uploads
- 15321408dd97beb7b5a94f0957b215cf
- black
- and
- white
- photography
- portrait
- of
- brad
- pitt
- jpg

Here's where I am so far:

```
import spacy
from nltk.tokenize import WordPunctTokenizer
from urllib.parse import urlparse


# Check if the word is noise
def is_noise(token, noisy_tags, min_token_length):     
    is_noise = False
    if token.pos_ in noisy_tags:
        is_noise = True 
    elif token.is_digit == True:
        is_noise = True
    elif token.is_stop == True:
        is_noise = True
    elif len(token.string) < min_token_length:
        is_noise = True
    return is_noise 

# Clean word
def clean_word(token, lower = True):
    if lower:
       token = token.lower()
    return token.strip()


nlp = spacy.load('en')

word_tokenizer = WordPunctTokenizer()

parsed_uri = urlparse(url)
text = '{uri.path} {uri.query} {uri.fragment}'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z\d\s]+', ' ', text)
text = ' '.join(word_tokenizer.tokenize(text))

document = nlp(text)
noisy_pos_tags = ['PROP']
cleaned_words = [clean_word(word.string) for word in document \
                                if not is_noise(word, noisy_pos_tags, 2)]

print(cleaned_words)
```

Update: Here I am adding the output for Part of speech tagging using Spacy:

```
word: 15321408dd97beb7b5a94f0957b215cf
word.lemma_: 15321408dd97beb7b5a94f0957b215cf
word.dep_: amod
word.shape_: ddddxxddxxxdxdxddxddddxdddxx
word.is_alpha: False
word.is_stop: False
```

**Update:** 
I have tried two other methods, one of which got me close.

*Method 1*
I was unable to actually retrain the classifier based on good and bad words: https://github.com/rrenaud/Gibberish-Detector

*Method 2*
Here is a second method but only works with longer text. In some cases there is only 1 word extracted and with this method it's always considered gibberish: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/894766/Gibberish-Classification-Algorithm-and-Implementat

Comment: Since hashes only consist number from 0 to 9 and character a to f. You can have some kind of check regarding it. You can also include checks related to the length of the string as to whether it's greater than some arbitrary number and it's a factor of 2 or not.

Comment: If you only want English words, can't you just drop strings containing numbers?  It looks like you don't care about the words `content`, `example`, and `uploads` - if all you really want are the words in the filename itself, `split` on `/` and parse the last element only.

Comment: @andrew_reece that's just a mistake on my part for not including those in the output. Splitting on `/` is not an option because we don't know the url's path depth. Can't simply just drop all words containing numbers because some company names contain numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using the good probabalistic approach provided by the gibberish-detector module. You can also use multiple signals provided by inbuilt corpuses in NLTK and Spacy.
NLTK examples (using brown and wordnet corpuses)

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from nltk.corpus import webtext
>>> brown.words()
[u'The', u'Fulton', u'County', u'Grand', u'Jury', ...]
>>> 'brad' in brown.words()
True
>>> 'pitt' in brown.words()
False
>>> '15321408dd97beb7b5a94f0957b215cf' in brown.words()
False
>>> 'photography' in brown.words()
True
>>> wordnet.synsets('photography')
[Synset('photography.n.01'), Synset('photography.n.02'), Synset('photography.n.03')]
>>> wordnet.synsets('brad')
[Synset('brad.n.01'), Synset('brad.v.01')]
>>> wordnet.synsets('pitt')
[Synset('pitt.n.01'), Synset('pitt.n.02'), Synset('pitt.n.03')]
>>> wordnet.synsets('15321408dd97beb7b5a94f0957b215cf')
[]
>>> wordnet.synsets('anothergibberishhash')
[]
```

These lookups are not optimized though, you would have to create optimized data structures to lookup these signals in real time instead of full iteration over the words in the corpus.